# Working with a user database and a data database in EF Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am looking for some help when working with two SQL databases for Entity Framework. One database is a scaffolded identity database using package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity` and the other is a database which holds core application information. For best practice I am keeping user data separate from other data.

**Question 1**

Consider I have my two database contexts created `UserContext` and `DataContext`. I have a class called `MyUserContext` which extends `IdentityUser` so I can add custom values to the users, for example:

```
public class MyUser : IdentityUser
{
    [PersonalData]
    public string FullName { get; set; } = String.Empty;
    [PersonalData]
    public byte[]? ProfilePicture { get; set; }
    public Guid CompanyId { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public Company? Company { get; set; }

    public bool isCompanyContact = false;

    public string? CompanyName()
    {
        return this.Company?.Name;
    }
}
```

Obviously as `Company` is `NotMapped`, it's null when a user is loaded. I know I need to call on my `DataContext` and load the company when I want to return the `CompanyName`, but where is best to do this? Can I do this inside of the `MyUser` class?

I am finding it really tricky to find resources on using two databases, specifically when one is a user database.

**Question 2**

I am really looking for some general best practices and beginner guides on how to use these databases together in my application. For example, when should I use `UserManager` and when should I create a `UserContext` instance and use that? Does it even matter?

Comment: *"For best practice I am keeping user data separate from other data..."* You can "keep" data in separate databases only if it has no relationships. If it does, as in your case `MyUser` <-> `Company`, they definitely should be in one and the same database in order to be able to use relational database constraints (and EF Core relationships).

Comment: Thank you for the information just to be clear you are suggesting that I keep user data in the same database as other data? The way i see it there will always be a link. If I start storing company data then anything that relates to company will be in the same database. It's a never ending cycle and means that user data is not separated. This seems like really bad practice to me.

Comment: Links do not support enforced FK relationships, which are essential in relational database world. And even though EF Core theoretically supports non relational databases, most of its features are tied to relational databases. Relationships (via navigation properties) are one of them. You can eventually fool it somehow, but in general all you get would be problems here and there. So yes, the best is to keep related data in one and the same database.